# While finding hero word switcher do the change on all of them

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I have a "hero word switcher", its only made to change 1 word at one spot, i was wondering if its possible to just set a while on the hero word switcher, so while it finds `$('#hero-word-switcher');` on the page, and should do the change or do i have to change the ID, and then copy the javascript?

```js
$(function() {

  // Hero word switcher

  var switcher = $('#hero-word-switcher');
  var delay = 2000;
  var count = switcher.find('strong').length;

  function calculateWidths() {
    switcher.find('strong').each(function(index) {
      $(this).attr('data-width', $(this).width());
    });
    switcher.width(switcher.find('.active').attr('data-width'));
  }
  calculateWidths();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    calculateWidths();
  });

  function doChange() {
    var nextItem;
    var currentItem = parseInt(switcher.find('.active').attr('data-oid'));

    if (currentItem == count - 1) {
      nextItem = 0;
    } else {
      nextItem = currentItem + 1;
    }

    switcher.addClass('in');

    switcher.find('[data-oid="' + currentItem + '"]').removeClass('active');
    switcher.find('[data-oid="' + nextItem + '"]').addClass('active');

    switcher.width(switcher.find('[data-oid="' + nextItem + '"]').attr('data-width'));
    setTimeout(doChange, delay);
  }

  setTimeout(doChange, delay);

});
```

```css
#hero-word-switcher.in strong.active {
  -webkit-animation: enter-word 300ms 100ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  -moz-animation: enter-word 300ms 100ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  animation: enter-word 300ms 100ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}
#hero-word-switcher strong.active {
  visibility: visible;
}
#hero-word-switcher {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-transition: width 400ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  -moz-transition: width 400ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  -ms-transition: width 400ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  transition: width 400ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-right: -5px;
}
#hero-word-switcher.in strong {
  -webkit-animation: leave-word 300ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  -webkit-transform-origin: center 35px;
  -moz-animation: leave-word 300ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  -moz-transform-origin: center 35px;
  transform-origin: center 35px;
}
#hero-word-switcher strong {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  margin-right: 10px
}
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
            I love text like <span id="hero-word-switcher" style="width: 84px;" class="in">
                <strong data-oid="0" data-width="116" class="active">Lorem1</strong>
                <strong data-oid="1" data-width="84">Lorem2</strong>
                <strong data-oid="2" data-width="183">Lorem3</strong>
            </span> 
            <span id="hero-word-switcher" style="width: 105px;" class="in">
                <strong data-oid="0" data-width="130" class="active">Ipsum1</strong>
                <strong data-oid="1" data-width="84">Ipsum2</strong>
                <strong data-oid="2" data-width="183">Ipsum3</strong>
            </span> !!
        </h1>
```

Comment: You can only use a given id once on the page; id must be unique. You can use a class however.

Comment: I didn't talk about in my post, because it's not important to answer your question, BUT: If you wanne do it right, you should create a jQuery Plugin. The create one, you can extend the `$.fn` namespace. You can read about it in the manual of jQuery. If you do so, you create a Plugin, that can be used in a way you are familiar with (`$('.hero-word-switcher').heroWordSwitcher({delay:2000});` and so on).

Comment: @Pointy that was also my point - but i was just looking for a way to check for all hero word switchers in the entire page. However i should have changed it to a class.

Comment: @JoshuaK I'm not familiar with jQuery Plugins, however it sounds a lot easier, if i was going to use it on many pages, but i just wanted it on the front page (home) - which i didn't mention in my post, but i was talking about "a page" or "the page" like in 1 page. But i would of consider your solution if like i metioned.. a larger site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the selector from the id-selector to a different one (e.g. class selector). After that you can easily use it on multiple positions. just change your code in a way like that:

```
$('.hero-word-switcher').each(function() {
  var switcher = $(this);
  var delay = 2000;
  ...
});
```

EDIT: `...` means you don't have to change the rest of your code. It should work, if I'm right. But I didn't test your code, so it is possible, that I missed something. In this case, pls comment on this post and I will take a look at it.

Comment: It's actually working, i was thinking of something that way, but i was totally gone on that one. It happens.. even to the best.